# What utility allows for the printing of diff results where the left and right sides are separate pages?

Tags: diff, utilities

I need a utility which allows me to do a diff and print each side on a separate sheet of paper. I've so far looked at WinMerge, ExamDiff Pro, Compare It, and SmartSVN's utility, and all of them allow the printing of diff results, but they put both sides on one sheet.

Essentially our formatting rules allow 120 character horizontal widths, and the word wrapping is making the printouts less effective. We can lower the font size, but then it's hard to read.

Free is better, but commercial will do. Syntax highlighting for Java is a plus.

**Edit:** Bonus points for a Win app, though I'll take nix app suggestions as backups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I ended up finding which satisfied the requirements was to purchase *ExamDiff Pro* which lets you print only the left or only the right sides of a diff. It would be nicer if there was a one-click "Print!" solution, but this is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The *NIX command is comm. We are working with beyond compare. Try finding some windows implementation of comm or run it in cygwin